# .Net Easy sharing of enums between different applications in different locations

Tags: c#, enums

Ok here is the problem...

Bob is in the UK writing a TCP Client.
Alice is in the US writing the TCP Server.

Bob has enums that relate to the commands and replies that the client can send.
Alice has enums that relate to the commands and replies that the server can send.

Whilst Bob and Alice are coding they are forever having to remember to share the enums with each other as the programs are developed.

The Question:

Is there a way that these can be shared more easily? As neither developer can code their side without knowing what the other side is doing and the enums are a very important part of the process.

Comment: Put the enums in a separate assembly, then reference this assembly from the client and server?

Comment: How would they easily share the assembly - without having to download it each time?

Comment: You just take out the common parts and put them in an separate assembly and then you don't change that assembly.

Comment: In addition to Lucas Trzesniewski suggestion: start developing *three* projects: Client, Server and *Shared library*

Comment: That does not make sharing the assembly any easier

Comment: @DaveGordon What other mechanism of sharing something are you potentially thinking of?  If both people need something, then someone has to download it at some point?  Perhaps the question you're really wanting to ask is about how people can collaborate on a project like this, and what tools are available to enable this - such as a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a protocol version to check compatibility. When the client is connected it sends its version to the server and the server can reply with an error if the client is not compatible. You can increment the version when a new enum value the client must know is added and decide whether the server should deny or work in compatibility mode with older clients.

Now you easily know when an update is required.

To make the update easier, create a separate project containing all consts and methods that are usefull for your protocol. Create a nuget package and use it in both client and server. With a proper nuget repository you can publish your updates and get them in one click from UK or US.

Answer (score 1):

Build a sync command that can request the enums from each other periodically or on command/startup. They can then compare it with their local enums and update it accordingly with some notification to recompile for the enum set has changed.